# Субсвойство свойства объекта

Tags: javascript

Чтобы не писать лишних проверок, можно после каждого свойства поставить знак `?`

```js
let data = { prop: { a: 8 }}

console.log( data.prop?.a ) // 8
console.log( data.prop?.b ) // undefined
console.log( data.propA.b ) // Cannot read properties of undefined
```

Возможно ли то же самое сделать на setter без проверок?

```js
let data = { prop: { a: 8 }}

// 
if (data.prop)
data.prop.b = 16

// 
data.prop && (data.prop.b = 16)

// 
data.propA.b = 16 // Cannot set properties of undefined
data.prop?.b = 16 // Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @nörbörnën, да я уже знаком с этим, как раз Proxy уже работает на данные. Действительно там и пропишу в обработчике, если не будет другого решения

Comment: @Doofy с прокси получится стучатся только на одно свойство дальше и там всё проверять

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, не обязательно, просто надо всегда Proxy возвращать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. К сожалению, `?.` поддерживается только для чтения, но не для записи.

Хотя, если нужно не проигнорировать присваивание, а создать новое свойство, то можно сделать так:

```js
var x
;((x??={}).smth??={}).a = 123
;((x??={}).smth??={}).b = 456
;(x??={}).other = 789
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Ох уж эти костыли  Проще тогда проверку поставить, у меня только два уровня свойств

Comment: вариант Кверти - совсем не костыльный

Comment: @nörbörnën ну как не костыльный? А что если свойств много будет? Там уже либо Proxy, либо вот такая длинная каша. Проверять каждый проперти и если его нет, то создавать пустой объект

Comment: @Doofy ну попробуй сделать Proxy, у тебя будет undefined. Попробуй сделать 5 свойств вперёд

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, вообще-то прокси может создавать свойство с новым прокси и так создастся вся цепочка. А ещё есть вариант вернуть промежуточный мусорный объект и выкинуть его (впрочем, чтение он будет тоже портить, тут надо обдумать лучше).

Comment: @Qwertiy покажи как это можно сделать, я не понимаю, если не сложно. Типа можно написать `a = {}; a.b.c.d.e = 5`; И будет нормально работать? перед этим засунуть объект a в Proxy

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, а можешь отдельным вопросом задать?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1371115/331312

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = { prop: { a: 8 }};

_.set(data, 'prop.b.c.d', 23);
console.log(data.prop.b.c.d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А без фреймворков можно?

Comment: @Doofy это не фреймворк, а библиотека

Comment: @Doofy да, просто идёшь в lodash github и переписываешь их функцию set

Comment: хотелось бы без дополнительных подключений, так-то я и сам мог написать костыли для таких вещей. Может есть возможность нативно это сделать

Comment: @Doofy ну я говорю нативно переписать функцию set из lodash

Comment: Вроде как не просили создавать?

Comment: @Qwertiy не просили, но минуя исключение приходится создавать либо пустой объект со свойствами, либо перед set ставить проверку на наличие свойства

Comment: @Doofy а если нужно 5 свойств вперёд, что делать?)

Comment: @МихаилКамахин мне не нужно в данном случае. Ну а вообще создавать пустой объект с этими субсвойствами. Собстна эта библиотека так и делает

Comment: @Doofy она намного больше делает и там много проверок. просто setter приведёт к большим ошибкам в будущем и нужно будет много чего переписывать