# Как добавлять значения к объекту, без ошибок, что нету объекта

Tags: javascript

Хочу понять, как добавлять свойства к объекту через Proxy, используя setter, например, так:

```js
const obj = {};
const proxyObj = superProxy(obj); // superProxy - функция, возвращающая Proxy
proxyObj.a.b.c.d = 5;
console.log(proxyObj.a.b.c.d); // 5
console.log(obj.a.b.c.d); // 5
```

Comment: Ну вряд ли set - там же путь строкой передаётся и сплитится. Конечно, такое тоже можно сделать, но это идиотизмом попахивает, и судя по комментам, ты всё-таки хотел цепочку. И вообще, лучше бы прям примеры привести, чего ожидается, а то так довольно много вариантов, чего можно намутить. А вообще, вечером отвечу.

Comment: @Qwertiy изменил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function superProxy(obj) {
  return obj !== Object(obj) ? obj : new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, name, receiver) {
      if (name === 'toJSON') return undefined; // fix for snippet output
      return superProxy(target[name] ??= Object.create(null))
    }
  })
}

const obj = {};
const proxyObj = superProxy(obj);

proxyObj.a.b.c.d = 5;
console.log(proxyObj.a.b.c.d);      // 5
console.log(obj.a.b.c.d);           // 5

obj.direct = { z: { u: 42 } };
proxyObj.direct.z.a.b.c = 88;
console.log(proxyObj.direct.z.u);   // 42
console.log(obj.direct.z.u);        // 42
console.log(proxyObj.direct.z.a.b); // Proxy {c: 88}
console.log(obj.direct.z.a.b);      // {c: 88}
```

[image: скриншот результата]

Comment: консолька не может Proxy сериализовать :) `console.log(proxyObj.direct.z.a.b); // Proxy {c: 88}` вот тут

Comment: @Grundy, что ж она такая? Я ж не перехватываю получение списка свойств - по идее оно должно нормально работать?

Comment: Тут что-то вроде - ты каждый раз отдаешь прокси, который она пытается сериализировать и получает опять прокси и так по кругу пока стек не переполнится :)

Comment: поправил код для сниппета.

Comment: @Grundy, а, понял. Прикольная штука.

Comment: а что делать с функциями? :)

Comment: @Grundy, с какими функциями?

Comment: Классно, только не понимаю, почему ты геттер менял. Я как думал: если у нас ошибки при записи в сеттер, надо его модифицировать. Почему нету ошибки при записи в сеттер? хмммммм

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, сеттер ничего не возвращает, кроме флага об успешности записи, так что с ним не получится. И вообще, сначала ведь геттеры вызываются при последовательном обращении через точку - там сеттеров в принципе нет, кроме самого присваивания. К тому же, я хотел сохранить объект чистым без прокси.

Comment: @Qwertiy понял, сложно, классно! )