# Прокси для реализации простого синтаксиса

Tags: javascript

Необходимо реализовать простой синтаксис через прокси

```js
let Компонент = {
  Form:{
    id:'qwerty', 
    elems:{
      elem1:{
        id:'test1'}, 
      elem2:{
        id:'test2'}
      }
    }
  };

Компонент = new Proxy(Компонент, {
  get(target, prop) {
      for (let elem in target){
          if(target[elem].id === prop)
              return target[elem];
      }
  }
});

console.log(Компонент.qwerty); //возвращает объект по id
// console.log(Компонент.qwerty.Элемент.test1); // нужно чтобы вернулся объект elem1
```

Comment: Покажите, что вы сделали и что именно не получается

Comment: Нифига не понял, но скорее всего это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1371142/178988.

Comment: @SwaD добавлен код в описание

Comment: что-то код в вопросе делает совсем не то, что в описании задачи указано